# How to solve Data truncated for column issue

Tags: mysql

It works on localhost but not in cpanel
How can I get rid from this error-

```
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'connectionMethod' at row 1
```

here is the MySQL code to create the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `file_server`;
CREATE TABLE `file_server` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serverLabel` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `serverType` enum('remote','local') DEFAULT NULL,
  `ipAddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `connectionMethod` enum('ftp') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ftp',
  `ftpPort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '21',
  `ftpUsername` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ftpPassword` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `storagePath` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `statusId` (`statusId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[Full Database](http://freefile.xyz/database/database.sql)

Comment: Are there any other values for column `connectionMethod` except 'ftp'?

Comment: its import in localhost properly but not in cpanel I have added the full database http://freefile.xyz/database/database.sql

Comment: This is just a **Warning**, is your data imported successfully?

Comment: no its not imported and its stopped installing. I am installing a php application for file share it's install successfully on Localhost but not in Cpanel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change (line 1298 in your script)

```
`INSERT INTO `file_server` VALUES ('1', 'Local Default', 'local', '', '', '0', '', null, '2', null);`
```

to

```
`INSERT INTO `file_server` VALUES ('1', 'Local Default', 'local', '', 'ftp', '0', '', null, '2', null);`
```

One more thing if your column name is enum then in that case if u also have specified the default value then you need not to specify or give that column any values.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the answer the previous error gone but a new error occur `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'availableValues' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: Line 1142, change to `availableValues varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFUALT '',`, and you should check your error and find the position where error happened, then try to fix it yourself. Am I all right?

Comment: You are right but unfortunately another error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'wait_between_downloads' cannot be null` I found . But why this error not shown on localhost ?

Comment: I think it is mostly the syntax checking is more strict in `Cpanel`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to change the query as follow:-

```
INSERT INTO `file_server` (`serverLabel`,`serverType`,`ipAddress`,`ftpPort`,`ftpUsername`,`ftpPassword`,`statusId`,`storagePath`) VALUES ('Local Default', 'local', '', '0', '', null, '2', null);
```

OR

If you need to insert values in all the columns then in that case you need to write the below query.

```
INSERT INTO `file_server` VALUES ('6', 'Local Default', 'local', '', 'ftp', '0', '', NULL, '2', NULL);
```